# Running beanstalkd worker on a remote server

Tags: php, laravel-4, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

My stack set-up consists of the following
**Machine1** - Main Server (Running laravel)
**Machine2** - MySql Server for the laravel codebase
**Machine3** - Beanstalkd worker


I have setup Supervisord on **Machine1** and added the following queue listener

```
[program:queue1]
command=php artisan queue:listen --queue=queue1 --tries=2
...
```

My laravel queue config file(app/config/queue.php) reads the following

```
'beanstalkd' => array(
    'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
    'host'   => '--- Machine3 IP ---',
    'queue'  => 'queue1',
    'ttr'    => 60,
),
```

And I have installed beanstalkd on **Machine3** along with Beanstalk console and can see my tasks being pushed to the queue and executing successfully. However I am not sure if **Machine3** is actually executing them, and the reason for my suspicion is the High CPU usage on the main server as compared to no spikes in CPU usage on **Machine3**

I completely shutdown my beanstalkd Server to check if the queue still processes and the outcome was an error reported by laravel indicating it could not connect to the beanstalkd server.

I read somewhere that you need to have your laravel codebase on the beanstalkd server(**Machine3**) too, was that really the way to go?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something very similar - using beanstalkd to facilitate communication between two Laravel microservices. Did you need to copy your Job class across the two projects to make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whichever machine you run `queue:listen` on is the machine that does the actual processing of the queue.

At the moment all you are doing is storing the queues on **machine3**, but processing them on **machine1**.

So you need to have **machine3** run the `queue:listen` command if you want it to process the queue.

Comment: So that does imply that I need to have my codebase (or atleast part of it that performs the queued jobs) on **machine3**, but will the jobs pushed by **machine1** be read and executed on **machine3** considering that both of them will be hooked to the same MySql server i.e **machine1**?

Comment: Correct. You should `git pull` your codebase onto **Machine3**. Or if you want, you could have a 'scaled down' version on **Machine3** - but it is usually easier to maintain just the one version.

Comment: Yep, will give that a try!
thank you for all your help!

Comment: So how actually get rid of the two versions of the codebase on two servers?

Comment: May be setup some kind of auto-sync between the primary and secondary code bases?