# Laravel queue external server

Tags: php, laravel, beanstalkd, laravel-5.1

I have the following servers configured:

`App Server` is running LAMP with Laravel 5.1
`Queue Server` is running Beanstalkd and Supervisord

I want to be able to send jobs in Laravel on the `App Server` to the `Queue Server` which will simply run a DB insert. I was hoping to use Laravel's job queueing to do this but from my understanding it would then require me to have the same Laravel project on both hosts? It seems like it sends the class to execute, not the data itself. Perhaps I have a bad understanding of how Beanstalkd works? Should I be using something like RabbitMQ instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465068/running-beanstalkd-worker-on-a-remote-server